# WSO2 ESB How to sign the message of the Custom Mediator

Tags: java, wso2, esb

Good day!
I am trying to sign XML in custom mediation with java and using government SDK when I signed with algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 it works well,

but when I am trying to sign with algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311 I got an error:

```
org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: The requested algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311 does not exist. Original Message was: null
Original Exception was java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.getSignatureAlgorithmSpi(SignatureAlgorithm.java:160)
        at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.<init>(SignatureAlgorithm.java:73)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.SignedInfo.<init>(SignedInfo.java:118)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(XMLSignature.java:256)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(XMLSignature.java:185)
        at kz.EsbGcvp.SignGcvp.SignXML(SignGcvp.java:113)
```

Code on Java is working well with two algorithms without deploy in Wso esb, but when I call it from Wso esb I get an error if will use `gost34310-gost34311.`

I think that problem with version xmlsec-000, I have already used versions `1.4.4, 1.4.8, 1.5.8`, but unsuccessfully.

So how can I set up WSO2 ESB or understand which version or type framework.jar i have to use? 
I have been using WSO2 ESB Version 6.4.0

Code in mediation:

```
private static String SignXML(String xmlDoc, String keyPath, String keyPass) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, Exception
{

    KalkanProvider provider = new KalkanProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KncaXS.loadXMLSecurity();       
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", provider.getName());
    System.getProperty("user.dir");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyPath), keyPass.toCharArray());
    String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
    String signMethod = null;
    String digestMethod = null;
    String sigAlgOid = certificate.getSigAlgOID();
    if (sigAlgOid.equals(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption.getId())) {
        signMethod =  Constants.MoreAlgorithmsSpecNS + "rsa-sha1";
        digestMethod = Constants.MoreAlgorithmsSpecNS + "sha1";
    } else if (sigAlgOid.equals(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption.getId())) {
        signMethod = Constants.MoreAlgorithmsSpecNS + "rsa-sha256";
        digestMethod = XMLCipherParameters.SHA256;
    } else {

        signMethod = Constants.MoreAlgorithmsSpecNS + "gost34310-gost34311";
        digestMethod = Constants.MoreAlgorithmsSpecNS + "gost34311";            
    }

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlDoc.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    StringWriter os = new StringWriter();
    XMLSignature signature;
    try {

        signature = new XMLSignature(doc, "", signMethod);                      
        if (doc.getFirstChild() != null) {
            doc.getFirstChild().appendChild(signature.getElement());
            Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
            transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);          
            transforms.addTransform(XMLCipherParameters.N14C_XML_CMMNTS);
            signature.addDocument("", transforms, digestMethod);
            signature.addKeyInfo(certificate);
            signature.addKeyInfo(certificate.getPublicKey());
            signature.sign(key);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
            os.close();
            return os.toString().replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("doc.getFirstChild() value is null.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы смогли решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be useful somebody.
Because this code are working as independent runnable JAR file, I took out logic to remote runnable JAR file and added it as addition tools to WSO2 ESB, so it works well. Maybe it can have bad influence for performance WSO2 ESB ..... , but I don't have big experience working with Java and ESB.